# GAC reference broken when Project moved from one machine to another

Tags: visual-studio, biztalk, gac

I have a BizTalk project which refers to a dll from GAC. When I move this project from one machine to another, the references are broken and I need to add those references again.

Is there a way to avoid this, because I have more than 50 projects which have references to GAC and are to be moved to another machine.

Comment: Adding references to DLLs stored in the GAC is drastically wrong.  Now you know why.  You need to keep a copy of them stored somewhere, it needs to be checked into source control if you don't build them yourself so you can always be sure that you can rebuild the solution at any place and at any time.

Comment: @HansPassant, I have to disagree with you on this one for this case - it's very likely that this DLL will have to ultimately be GACed for use by BizTalk either way, and referncing a local copy can end up with very difficult to track down issues vs. referncing the one in the GAC that BizTalk will actually use in the runtime.  Full answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can avoid this problem by GAC'ing all the referenced Assemblies on the new machine **before** migrating the projects.  Just like they are on the current machine.  There is really nothing wrong with this.

Visual Studio behaves differently when referencing GAC'ed Assemblies.  I don't know what the exact rules are but frequently, Visual Studio will display a reference to the GAC even when an Assembly outside the GAC was chosen as the Reference target.  I say display a GAC'ed reference because if you examine the project file, only the Assembly's string name list listed, not the full path.  Visual Studio probes the GAC first and if a match is found, that's what it uses.

This is all Visual Studio behavior and not directly related to BizTalk.

Answer (score 0):

For BizTalk Projects, this is not bad practice - BizTalk will be pulling the library from the GAC (not from wherever your assembly thinks it is when it gets built).  Referencing a local DLL or solution can lead to very challenging scenarios where the local copy of the DLL never got GACed, and behavior that works in a unit test doesn't work in BizTalk.  The solution is simple: GAC the assembly on the new machine.

There are two scenarios possible here - you're trying to reference an assembly you build yourself (like a C# utilities library), or you're referencing a 3rd party DLL.

If the first, then in the Post Build events for that C# library, add some logic to GAC the assembly after building it.  For example,

```
call "$(DevEnvDir)..\Tools\vsvars32.bat"
gacutil /if "$(TargetPath)"
```

Then, just make sure you build that project first.

Otherwise, if you're referencing a pre-built library, add similar logic to the **prebuild** stage of the dependent project - and include the library as a resource in your solution (in source control).

Comment: You are installing VS on a BizTalk server??  Hard to imagine that this is a common practice.

Comment: In a development environment it's required.  You install VS first, then install BizTalk Server - usually the developer version.  When you go to deploy your assemlies, the references are to the GAC, where the assemblies will have to go for BTS anyway.